# Keeping buttons inside a div fixed on top even when page scrolls or content is added

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div in which the content would be dynamic and should be resizable. When  the div is resized or there is more content, the buttons go out of view. But, I need to have the buttons visible at all times. Difficulty is I cannot change the html structure and need to use inline styling for it.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/M6zGc/)

```
<div class="txt">
Resizable content
</div>
```

Please suggest.Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this meet your needs?

```
<span id="ab" style="display:inline-block;position:fixed; right:0; top:0px;">
```

If this doesn't work for you then you would have to have access to the markup or be allowed to use JS/jQuery to manipulate the DOM

Comment: Thank you for your help, this does help, but seems eventually gota use jquery for this as there are multiple instances.